# Finding the most changed files in a repository through GitHub API

Tags: git, github

I am looking for a way to find out the most changed files in a repo, either by commits, deletes etc. However, I could not find a way to replicate the "git log" command through GitHub API. Is there a way to find this out through the API?

I've tried searching the GitHub documentation and the closest I've found is the "GET /search/commits" API. I could only sort these by date or author, and not frequency of changes.

Comment: This type of ask seems to be a specific need and I don't think it's the kind of things github provide. [GitExtra](https://github.com/tj/git-extras) is [doing this well](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-effort)

Comment: Hmm I see.. Is there by any chance an API for GitExtra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this operation, you need to walk every revision in the repository.  The GitHub API is not meant to walk revisions, because it's expensive and hard to return large amounts of data to the user, especially in a RESTful way.  In general, any sort of object-oriented (as opposed to RPC) API will be bad at doing this efficiently.

GitHub does [provide a small number of statistics](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/), but they're all equivalent to the charts that are already existing in the UI and what you're requesting is not among them.

If you want to do this, you'll need to clone the repository onto your computer and either script something yourself or using a tool like GitExtra, as mentioned.  This will be far faster than using the GitHub API, even including the time it takes to download the repository, and you won't run into rate limits.